# Creating a data table

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

First off I have an app that provides the user information about the amount of air miles they have travelled based on their input. This information is displayed in many different conversions on a `UITableView`, for example it shows the amount of centimeters you have travelled and the amount of kilometers you have travelled. All the values are `double`, now what I want to do with this data is share it. I have decided to choose Facebook, In-App Email, SMS and Twitter. I **could** display/share the data like this:

```
Kilometres      2000.28

Miles          1400.33

Centimetres     20000000.238 

Yards            100039.02
```

(Values are made up)

But that would be impractical and quite ugly, especially for twitter. So I had an idea to display it as a data table template, like below. (Except with the text in of course!) How could I do this? Would I display it and attach it as an image, or text? Are there any APIs out there that can do this?

Visual Representation:

[image: Data Table]

Comment: Why not just shorten it for twitter then?  Make the user select only one of those values to share and explain somewhere about the character limit.

Comment: What do you mean, "like below"? I'm trying to get a visual of what you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: sorry I thought I published it, I'm so stupid ill put it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dynamically create a UIView with the layout you want and turn that into an image via `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, example class method below. After generating the UIImage post that to Facebook..

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
}
```

Comment: ahhh I never thought of that, great idea! Accepted!